# Toggle between content with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.css.

I have a top navigation bar which will normally show a menu with hover-over popup for sub items.

[image]

But when the collapsed is set due to @media constraints, I want to show the content as nested `<select>` and `<Option>` elements.

[image]

Clicking the menu button will show content like this:
[image]

I am not sure how to perform an inverse collapse. I have tried collapse, collapse.in, etc. styles.

I want to show one content when collapsed and another if not collapsed. Both content areas need to show in the navbar area.

I would like to do pure CSS with no javascript.

The following is the HTML I want to hide when callapsed. I have not created the HTML with the select/option tags yet.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-if="userData.isAdminUser" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a>Managment</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#/users/">Employees</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/groups/">Groups</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/products/">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/skills/">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/levels/">Levels</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code, html and css. Without that, it makes it difficult to help.

Comment: Basically I want to replace the dropdown menu with select/option tags.

Comment: So you are wanting to put a `select` menu in the navbar? What is your issue? What have you tried? We need examples that show effort was put in and something that shows your problem clearly.